# Firebase App Distribution with apk splits unable to find apk

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-app-distribution

I'm trying to bend firebase app distribution to work with apk splits.
I almost have it, however my issue is this

```
Could not find the APK. Make sure you build first by running ./gradlew assemble[Variant], 
or set the apkPath parameter to point to your APK
```

My task

```
task firebaseAllEnvRelease() {
        group = "publishing"

        dependsOn ordered(
                ":printVersionCode",
                ":foo:app:assembleAllRelease"
                ":foo:app:firebasePublishAllEnvRelease")
    }
```

For whatever reason, the firebase task runs the apk check (not upload) beforehand, before assemble, so obviously the apk is not there -- how can I force it to respect the order of tasks?

*I know gradle creates the tasks graph hopwever it likes*, but I do have a utility `ordered` for what, which chains them via `mustRunAfter` and it is for sure correct.

Plan b is to run the assemble ina separate gradlew command before that, that works but -- why :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the gradle plugin

1. doesn't declare dependency on `assemble` task (in general, regardless of apk splits, by gradle convention, you shouldn't just "expect" the apks to be there)
2. doesn't generate tasks per apk splits -- but you do for flavors

So here is the work around for it:

```
// Generate firebase app distribution task variants for all abis
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
variant.outputs.all { output ->
def abi = output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)

if (abi == null) return
def abiName = abi.replace("_", "").replace("-", "")
task("appDistributionUpload${abiName.capitalize()}${variant.name.capitalize()}", type: com.google.firebase.appdistribution.gradle.UploadDistributionTask_Decorated) {
appDistributionProperties = new com.google.firebase.appdistribution.gradle.AppDistributionProperties(
new com.google.firebase.appdistribution.gradle.AppDistributionExtension(),
project,
variant
)
appDistributionProperties.apkPath = output.outputFile.absolutePath
appDistributionProperties.serviceCredentialsFile = project.file("secrets/ci-firebase-account.json")
appDistributionProperties.releaseNotes = abi
appDistributionProperties.groups = "ra-testers"
 
// Add dependsOn respective assemble task, so it actually
// builds apk it wants to upload, not just expect it to be there
dependsOn "assemble${variant.name.capitalize()}"
}
}
}
```

Comment: thats my code code I sent you on support lint, but thanks